# Extracting subsets of data

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, r

this seems to be an easy task really, but being completely new to the world of programming, I have problems with the following task:
I have a huge file which has the following format:

```
track type= wiggle name09
variableStep chrom=chr1
34 5 
36 7 
54 8 
variableStep chrom=chr2 
33 4 
35 2 
78 7 
this is text with the word random in it# this we need to remove
82 4 
88 6 
variableStep chrom=chr3 
78 5 
89 4 
56 7
```

now what I would like as an out put is just

one file called 1 
and containing only

```
34 5
36 7
54 8

a second file called 2

33 4
35 2
78 7
82 4 
88 6

a third file

78 5
89 4
56 7
```

It would be great to get some help on this...
If any knows how to do it in R... that would be even better

Comment: Does `sometext_sometext` begin with digits?

Comment: no...
the format would be
variableStep chrom=chr1
data
data
data
variableStep chrom=chr2
data
data
...

Comment: actually it will go until chr22 and then continue with chrx.

Comment: give an actual sample and don't ppl guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the following help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 1;
my $flag;
my $fh;

while (<>) {
    if (/^\d+\s+\d+\s*$/) {
        if ( $flag == 1 ) {
            $flag = 0;
            open $fh, '>', $filename;
            $filename++;
        }
        print $fh $_;
    }
    elsif (/random/) {
        next;
    }
    else {
        $flag = 1;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Save the above as `extract` (or any other name, if that matters).

Assuming that the file with data is named `file`.

```
perl extract /path/to/file
```

Comment: A programming newbie is probably going to need some instructions on how to use that Perl script...

Comment: maybe... I don't understand the regular expressions... but let me try... thanks

Comment: @Tamir: The regular expression checks if the line starts with digits, then has some spaces, and digits again to the end of the line. If so, we write the line to the file.

Comment: Cool!!! it works! Some minor things... it gets the naming wrong... basically it calls file 1 file no 2 and so on. 
Secondly, within the data blocks there are single rows of text that i need to get rid off before I can use the script above... they are all different, but they share that the word "random" occurs within each of them

Comment: @Alan I see I think I can make sense of the regular expressions now

Comment: How should the naming be? Sorry, I did not understand your second point.

Comment: I don't see why, but it produced an empty 1 file and then went on and put the first chunk of data into 2. 

There are rows which do not contain data but text. Usually they are ok, but the code above starts a new file whenever he comes across them. All of them can be identified since they have the word "random" within their text. How could we get rid of them before running the data extraction.?

Comment: Can you please provide some parts of the original data file so that I can understand the format better?

Comment: track type= wiggle name09
variableStep chrom=chr1
34 5
36 7
54 8
variableStep chrom=chr2
33 4
35 2
78 7
this is text with the word random in it
82 4
88 6
variableStep chrom=chr3
78 5
89 4
56 7

Comment: track type= wiggle name09 \n variableStep chrom=chr1 \n 34 5 36 7 54 8 variableStep chrom=chr2 33 4 35 2 78 7 this is text with the word random in it 82 4 88 6 variableStep chrom=chr3 78 5 89 4 56 7

Comment: sorry I don't know how to make it look nicer... it does not show line breaks

Comment: Can you please update your question with the above data? You can `code` it there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in R.

Load your data:

```
a <- readLines(textConnection("track type= wiggle name09
variableStep chrom=chr1
34 5 
36 7 
54 8 
variableStep chrom=chr2 
33 4 
35 2 
78 7 
this is text with the word random in it# this we need to remove
82 4 
88 6 
variableStep chrom=chr3 
78 5 
89 4 
56 7"))
```

Process it by finding the break points and only keeping rows with number space number format:

```
idx <- grep("=", a)
idx <- idx[c(which((idx[-1]-idx[-length(idx)])>1),length(idx))]
idx <- cbind(idx+1,c(idx[-1]-1,length(a)))
sapply(1:nrow(idx), function(i) {
    x <- a[idx[i,1]:idx[i,2]]
    write.table(x[grep("^\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s*", x, perl=TRUE)], file=as.character(i), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Hi Shane, where would it write it to? I usually specify a directory when I use write.table

Comment: Except for the first chunk of data (1), the code gives funny results, mixing data and leaving the text inside

Comment: Hi Shane, it is not quite working, now it returns only the first lines without the data? It does something though... Thank you for taking the time

Comment: Well, it works with your sample data.  Not sure what to tell you without more information.

Comment: Updated it again using the same regex as Alan's solution.

Comment: Hi Shane... thank you! It nearly works, however it mixes the data a little bit. for example: Reads after the random line are not found in the file they should be but mixed with the next one... I don't know how to show a better snippet of the data... The real data contains between 10 and 80 million lines. However Alis code has helped me a lot. As well as yours, since I had never used readlines before...

Comment: Try changing the part where it say "=" to "variableStep chrom=chr".